# Update key value dictionary list?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, dictionary, unity-game-engine

Ok, there are answers for doing this with normal dictionary but the size of my dictionary / things to be stored is constantly changing, so I thought use a list. Here is what Im storing:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<GameObject, float>> planesFilled;
```

I have to continually update the values (and add  pairs if they spawn and don't already exist in the list in my update function. I am storing the distance between the objects and another object in scene.

I am having errors relating to  not being able to call `Contains` for just a key - I dont necessarily know the past value. My key should be the Gameobject.

What I have so far:

```
foreach(GameObject plane in anchorManager.planesSpawned)
        {
            if (ContainsKeyValue(planesFilled.ToDictionary(), plane)) { //dont know value
            } else {
                planesFilled.Add (new KeyValuePair<GameObject, float>(plane, GetDistanceBetweenObjs(plane.transform, botController.transform)));
            }
            //planesFilled[plane] = new KeyValuePair<GameObject, float>(plane, GetDistanceBetweenObjs(plane.transform, botController.transform));

            //list.Add(new KeyValuePair<double,double>(p.Key,p.Value));
            planesFilled.Sort((pair1,pair2) => pair1.Value.CompareTo(pair2.Value));
        }
```

This func is started but doesnt exactly work in my scenario:

```
public bool ContainsKeyValue<TKey, TVal>(Dictionary<TKey, TVal> dictionnaire,
        TKey expectedKey,
        TVal expectedValue) where TVal : IComparable
    {
        TVal actualValue;

        if (!dictionnaire.TryGetValue(expectedKey, out actualValue))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return actualValue.CompareTo(expectedValue) == 0;
    }
```

How can I update the values of existing objects or add new ones to my list dictionary situation?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you should just use a `Dictionary`. Dictionaries can change size over time.  The functions are are trying to create already exist as part of `Dictionary`, and calling the `ToDictionary` function in a loop will really hurt your performance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "but the size of my dictionary / things to be stored is constantly changing, so I thought use a list"? It's fine for entries to be added and removed from a dictionary.

Comment: If you need to sort the values for some reason, there is also a `SortedDictionary` class.

Comment: Also, you have `planesFilled.ToDictionary()` in a loop, which sounds like it's creating a new dictionary just to check whether a key is present. That *strongly* suggests you should just be using a dictionary of some kind - as James says, quite possibly a SortedDictionary (or SortedList, which is really a sorted dictionary, just named based on its implementation).

Comment: @JamesFaix Really? Ok did not know that. How would see if a dictionary contains just a key then?

Comment: Skyguy If want to get a value, use `TryGetValue(key, out value)` (as you already are), if you just want to check if a key exists, use `ContainsKey(key)`.

Comment: What @john said.  Other helpful members you might find on `Dictionary` are `Values` which returns a sequence of just the values, `Keys` which returns a sequence of just the keys, and `ContainsValue(value)` which lets you check for the existence of a value. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx for the full list of members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I update the values of existing objects or add new ones to my
>   list dictionary situation?

I can't answer about your "list dictionary"; and I'm not sure what is making you hesitant about using an actual [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). But if you did, you could do:

```
yourDictionary["yourKey"] = yourData;
```

Which will [add or upate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) a dictionary pair.